# can i use topological navigation in groovy?

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am using ubuntu 12.04 and ros groovy. is there anyway i can install it on groovy or anything i can do to use it? and any tutorial on this? thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115271/can-i-use-topological-navigation-in-groovy?/) by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2014-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well. I think the short answer is NO...

The original topological_navigation stack was intended for ROS Diamondback, and Koen kindly ported it to  Fuerte. However, after Groovy things changed a lot in ROS. It may require a very big effort to port the stack to "morden" ROS versions. We are still using the Fuerte version in our experiments and will also be very grateful if someone can port it to Hydro or Indigo. Actually, we are assessing the pains and gains of porting it to Indigo ourselves, just in case that we will have a clear need for it and no one's considering doing the tedious work.

---

Originally posted by [Vova Niu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19788/vova-niu/) with karma: 56 on 2015-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1